# Alter table and set default as current date

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table, date-arithmetic, sql-null

while creating a table I forgot to add a date of birth column. Is there a way to add a NOT NULL column to a table with default value being current date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alter table`. In MySQL 8.0:

```
alter table mytable 
    add datetime_of_birth datetime 
    not null
    default (current_date);
```

In earlier versions, you can't however, have a `date` column whose value defaults to `current_date`. This feature is supported for `datetime`s a and `timestamp`s column only. If you can live with a `datetime` column, then:

```
alter table mytable 
    add datetime_of_birth datetime 
    not null
    default current_timestamp;
```

You can then ignore the time portion of the column when querying it. If that's not an acceptable solution, then you need to implement the logic with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Use `alter table`:

```
alter table t add column date_of_birth date;
```

Comment: i need the column to not have null values

Answer (score 0):

If your table has rows of data in it, you must either add the column as nullable, or else give it a DEFAULT that will be assigned on every row.

If you don't give a DEFAULT, then a NOT NULL column will attempt to add the "default default." A date's default is `'0000-00-00'` which is an invalid date, and it will be rejected if you have strict mode set (which I do recommend):

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> alter table mytable add column date_of_birth date not null;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'date_of_birth' at row 1
```

The DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data types can be given a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
mysql> alter table mytable add column date_of_birth datetime not null default current_timestamp;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But you said you wanted a column that is DATE, which doesn't allow this:

```
mysql> alter table mytable add column date_of_birth date not null default current_timestamp;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'date_of_birth'
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use expressions as defaults (note the extra parentheses around the expression, which are required):

```
mysql> alter table mytable add column date_of_birth date not null default (curdate());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If you're using an earlier version of MySQL, then you can't do this in one ALTER TABLE. You must first add the column as a nullable column, then use UPDATE to backfill values into all the existing rows, then ALTER TABLE again to modify the column to be NOT NULL.